# Excel VBA to call a single macro by mutliple independent worksheet changes

Tags: vba, excel, validation, macros

I have used the following Worksheet Change VBA code which is applied to a single cell reference, and is used to call a macro dependent on selection from a data validation list.  The event triggered by the macro applies to the row of the active cell.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address(True, True) = "$H$2" Then
    Select Case Target
        Case "Yes"
            Call StandardEntry
        Case Else
            'Do nothing
    End Select
End If
End Sub
```

I would now like to be able to apply this worksheet change event to be triggered by individual cells within the same column, generating the same event within the active cells row and not affecting any other rows.  Identical data validation has been applied to the other cells in the column.

I would appreciate assistance in writing the appropriate code or adjusting the code above to suit.

Comment: `StandardEntry`, which you don't show, will be part of the solution here, so maybe show it?

Comment: Do you mean you just want to invoke `StandardEntry` when any cell in column H is changed and has a value of "Yes"?   If so, perhaps change `If Target.Address(True, True) = "$H$2" Then` to `If Target.Column = 8 Then`.  (But, if that is what you mean, the word "consecutive" in your question is confusing.)

Comment: @YowE3K yes that is exactly what I mean and the code change works perfectly.  Thanks!  I will now edit my question to remove the confusion and then add this as the answer.  Thanks again.  I appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @YowE3K!
Changing

```
If Target.Address(True, True) = "$H$2" Then
```

to

```
If Target.Column = 8 Then
```

did the trick and is a really simple solution!  Yeehar!

Comment: Don't forget that `Target` can be a multi-cell range, and `Target.column` will return the column of the top-left cell in a larger range...

Comment: Either use `Target.Cells.Count <> 1` or `For Each rng In Target`, `Dim rng As Range` and `If rng.Column = 8 Then`.